# NSerciceBus SetMessageId actually set correlationId?

Tags: nservicebus, .net-7.0

in my .Net project I need to set the MessageId of the message I send to an Azure ServiceBus Queue, so I have code like this:

```
sendOptions.SetMessageId(message.MessageId);

MessageSession.Send(command, sendOptions, cancellationToken);
```

Where `MessageSessions` is an instance of NServiceBus.IMessageSession

But, when I peek at the messages, I see unrelated GUID are used for message ID and the value I set is used for correlationId instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are two message IDs, logical and physical. `SetMessageId` is for logical message ID. Physical message ID is set by NServiceBus and cannot be mutated. You could try working around it by [customizing the native outgoing message](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/native-message-access#access-to-the-native-azure-service-bus-outgoing-message) but if you re-use MessageId and have delayed retries, it won’t be compatible with ASB transport and queue configuration, that could have native de-dup enabled.

Comment: The content of Peticular's documentations is very misleading then https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-identity.

My understanding about native Nservicebus de-dup is you need outbox enabled, is that so because I'd rather avoid adding a data store to my project.

Comment: There's a Feedback button 